# how to solve this type of compilation error?

Tags: java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DjPageDownloader {


    public URL url;
    public InputStream is = null;
    public DataInputStream dis;
    public String line;

    public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
            dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

            while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
             mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }

    }
```

this on compilation shows error as:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field url
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field is
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field url
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field dis
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field is
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field line
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field dis
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field line
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field is

    at djPageDownloader.DjPageDownloader.main(DjPageDownloader.java:16)
```

Comment: what portion of the error message was not understandable?

Comment: Googling would have solved this for you in seconds.

Comment: this was my mistake i should have searched it more on google.

Comment: @DeepakkumarJha Please mark someone as the correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make all of your fields static if you are just calling them from the Main class. You can't call an instance field from a static position, as you aren't currently in an instance. If you wish to keep them non-static, you have to make an instance of DjPageDownloader by putting it in a constructor, and calling that, like so:

```
public DjPageDownloader() {
    try {
        url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
         mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
}
```

Then call that in your main method:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    new DjPageDownloader();//If you use it more later, store to a variable, but atm you aren't
}
```

Comment: I would say that it is bad practice to actually run code in a constructor. You should use a constructor to initialize data.

Comment: Yes, I was just showing how he would use instance variables in an instance, rather than in a static context

Answer (score 3):

```
public static URL url;
public static InputStream is = null;
public static DataInputStream dis;
public static String line;
```

or

```
public class DjPageDownloader {

public static void main(String []args){

    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String line;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    ...
```

Comment: You're right! Copypaste error :( Anyway, your approach is better :)

Comment: Haha, yeah, figured that ;) But thanks, just depends on if he needs to keep referencing them or not too, which we don't really know

Comment: 3rd option: move the logic from main() to an instance method ('readUrl'). Then in main() create an instance of DjPageDownloader and call readUrl on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `url`, `is`, `dis`, and `line` fields from a static method, `main()`. So they either have to be static themselves or you have to call them from a non-static method, like a constructor, and `main()` instantiates the `DjPageDownloader` class.

Answer (score 0):

Move all of your field declarations to within your main method.  You're not using the object itself, just the main method.

Answer (score 0):

static methods can only access static methods and static variables from outside the method. So, from the main method, if you want to access any method or variable from outside the method, you must make static reference to them.